# LxQt on WSLg doesn't fit the full screen

Tags: desktop-environment, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lxqt

I installed `LxQt` on `WSL2` under `Windows 11`. I have several questions:

1. the `LxQt` screen doesn't fit the whole monitor screen, as shown in the figure, how could customize it?

[image]

2. the toolbar panel is hidden, press the WIN key is dominated by `Windows 11`, so I couldn't find the start menu of `LxQt`
3. can start `LxQt` by command line `startlxqt`, but how could add `LxQt` to the `Windows 11` start menu?

Comment: Adding custom WSLg/Windows Start menu items should really be a separate question, but see my [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1679587/1210833).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here should be very similar to [the one I gave on Ask Ubuntu regarding WSLg and Xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385747/1165986).

WSGg uses Wayland/Weston/Xwayland (via RDP extensions and a separate Mariner "System" distro) to display GUI apps in Windows 11.

The Weston Window Manager is already running in the current Wayland session, so it's difficult to launch a separate fullscreen desktop/window manager over the top of that.

The solution here seems to be the same as for Xfce4 -- Launch a fullscreen Xwayland session.  While it will be running under WSLg's Weston instance, it can have its own desktop and window manager.

Assuming you are on Ubuntu (which I am assuming, since you posted there), first:

```
sudo apt install xwayland
```

I've updated my launch technique for desktops under WSLg's Xwayland slightly since my Ask Ubuntu answer.  I currently recommend creating something like:

`lxqt-weston.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
Xwayland :1 &
xw_pid=$!
WAYLAND_DISPLAY= DISPLAY=:1 startlxqt
kill $xw_pid
```

A few important notes:

- I'm assuming that you installed the `openbox` package when installing LxQt.  If not, make sure you do, and select it as your window manager when launching LxQt for the first time.
- It's really important to remember that a lot of desktop services rely on either Systemd or physical hardware that might not exist in WSL2 (or both).  You may run into issues with some features as a result.
- I run into a regular issue when Alt-tabbing (Windows) between Windows Terminal and Xwayland where mouse clicks won't register.  Tapping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (not together) seems to "unstick" whatever is causing the problem.

Comment: thank you very much. I run your script, but the new top window is completely dark, only the mouse is visible, and I think the LxQt is not started

Comment: @JohnPaulQiangChen I'd agree that a "completely dark window" likely means that Xwayland is running, but LxQt is not.  Try it from the command-line, but in two separate WSL windows (or using `tmux` or equivalent).  First start `Xwayland :1` (without the background `&`), then in a separate window start `WAYLAND_DISPLAY= DISPLAY=:1 startlxqt`.  Is there any indication in the output as to the problem?

Comment: @JohnPaulQiangChen Just to confirm, not even the "Please select your default Window Manager" dialog appears for you, right?  Have you tried exiting the WSL instance, issuing `wsl --shutdown` and restarting?  I just tried again on a completely fresh instance, `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install -y xwayland lxqt openbox`.  That's *all* I did, and at that point the script works.  It opens the "Welcome to LxQt - Please select your default Window Manager" dialog.  I select "OpenBox", then I get the desktop.

Comment: Thank you very much, both your answer and comments work. I checked, and found copy and paste to `vim` in WSL2 produces`^M` at each newline, so I need to manually remove them